# Confusion over wire\array notation in Verilog

Tags: verilog

What's the meaning of `wire [a:b] c`? Is it different from `wire [b:a] c`? or does Verilog consider them equal? Is there any syntax to convert different arrays to each other?

Comment: One is reversed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109459/how-to-dynamically-reverse-the-bit-position-in-verilog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the meaning of wire [a:b] c??is it different from wire [b:a] c

Verilog does not assume the [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of buses.

For example

```
wire [7:0] C; //Little endian [7] [6] [5] [4] [3] [2] [1] [0]
wire [0:7] D; //Big endian    [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7]
```

In order to select the [Most significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) of C, you need to reference C[7]. While in order to to this for D, you need to reference D[0]

If you are trying to connect two busses together in Verilog they are connected *MSB to MSB* and *LSB to LSB*

So in the above example if we are trying to connect C and D together the LSB of C which is C[0] will be connected to the LSB of D which is D[7]

If C and D are not the same length

```
wire [7:0] C;
wire [0:3] D;
```

When you try to connect them together in Verilog they are connected starting from the LSB

In this case;

C : [7] [6] [5] [4] [3] [2] [1] [0]

...........................|....|....|....|

D : ....................[0] [1] [2] [3]

C[0] => D[3]

C[1] => D[2]

C[2] => D[1]

C[3] => D[0]

> verilog considers them equal?

Well they are both multi-bit wires there is no difference between them

> how to use it??

Just don't connect big-endian to little-endian unless you really mean to do this. Otherwise this might not give you the results you expect

Comment: It's about the same in VHDL. You can create vectors with the notation std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) or std_logic_vector(0 to 7). This will determine the order of the bits.